# How to get individual column value from sqflite database flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

```
// THis is model>>    
class CompanyProfile {
      // to create name tag for database
      static const String columnId = '_id';
      static const String comapnyNametag = 'CompanyName';
      static const String phoneNumbertag = 'PhoneNumber';
      static const String addressLine1tag = 'AddressLine1';
      static const String addressLine2tag = 'AddressLine2';
      static const String emailaddresstag = 'EmailAddress';
      static const String invPrefixtag = 'InvoicePrefix';
      static const String footerTexttag = 'FooterText';
    
      // to create new Profile or Update profile
      int? id;
      String? companyName;
      String? addressLine1;
      String? addressLine2;
      String? emailAddress;
      String? phoneNumber;
      String? invPrefix;
      String? footerText;
    
      CompanyProfile({
        this.id,
        this.companyName,
        this.addressLine1,
        this.addressLine2,
        this.emailAddress,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.invPrefix,
        this.footerText,
      });
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        var map = <String, dynamic>{
          comapnyNametag: companyName,
          phoneNumbertag: phoneNumber,
          addressLine1tag: addressLine1,
          addressLine2tag: addressLine2,
          emailaddresstag: emailAddress,
          invPrefixtag: invPrefix,
          footerTexttag: footerText,
        };
        if (id != null) {
          map[columnId] = id;
        }
        return map;
      }
    
      CompanyProfile.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        id = map[columnId];
        companyName = map[comapnyNametag];
        phoneNumber = map[phoneNumbertag];
        addressLine1 = map[addressLine1tag];
        addressLine2 = map[addressLine2tag];
        emailAddress = map[emailaddresstag];
        invPrefix = map[invPrefixtag];
        footerText = map[footerTexttag];
      }
    }
```

//this is databasae helper to create database

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import '../models/company_profile.dart';

class ProfileProvider {
  static const _dbName = 'profile.db';
  static const _dbVersion = 1;
  static Database? _db;

  String tableName = 'profile';
  String columnId = '_id';
  String comapnyNametag = 'CompanyName';
  String phoneNumbertag = 'PhoneNumber';
  String addressLine1tag = 'AddressLine1';
  String addressLine2tag = 'AddressLine2';
  String emailaddresstag = 'EmailAddress';
  String invPrefixtag = 'InvoicePrefix';
  String footerTexttag = 'FooterText';

  ProfileProvider._privateConstructor();
  static final ProfileProvider instance = ProfileProvider._privateConstructor();

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await _createDB();
    return _db;
  }

  _createDB() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(dir.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          
      create table $tableName (
        $columnId integer primary key autoincrement,
        $comapnyNametag text not null,
        $phoneNumbertag text not null,
        $addressLine1tag text not null,
        $addressLine2tag text not null,
        $emailaddresstag text not null,
        $invPrefixtag text not null,
        $footerTexttag text not null

      ) 

        ''');
  }

  Future<CompanyProfile> insert(CompanyProfile profile) async {
    final db = await database;
    profile.id = await db!.insert(tableName, profile.toMap());
    return profile;
  }

  // Future<CompanyProfile> getProfile(int id) async {
  //   final db = await database;
  //   final maps = await db.query(
  //     tableName,
  //     columns:
  //      )
  // }

  // Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
  //   final db = await database;
  //   return await db!.insert(tableName, row);
  // }



  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
    final db = await database;
    return await db!.query(tableName);
  }

  // Future<List<CompanyProfile>> profiledetails() async {
  //   final db = await database;
  //   final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
  //       db!.query(tableName) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  //   return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  //     return CompanyProfile(
  //       id: maps[i][columnId],
  //       companyName: maps[i][comapnyNametag],
  //       phoneNumber: maps[i][phoneNumbertag],
  //       addressLine1: maps[i][addressLine1tag],
  //       addressLine2: maps[i][addressLine2tag],
  //       emailAddress: maps[i][emailaddresstag],
  //       invPrefix: maps[i][invPrefixtag],
  //       footerText: maps[i][footerTexttag],
  //     );
  //   });
  // }
  Future<Iterable<CompanyProfile>> getProfile() async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult = await db!.query(tableName);
    return queryResult.map((e) => CompanyProfile.fromMap(e));
  }

  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    final db = await database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db!
        .update(tableName, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    return await db!.delete(tableName, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

 
}
// this is database helper
```

Using this model I was able to save data in the database.

//From debug Console.

{_id: 1, CompanyName: a, PhoneNumber: a, AddressLine1: a, AddressLine2: a, EmailAddress: a, InvoicePrefix: a, FooterText: a}

Now I Want to get the values and show in a profile screen like this:

Company Name: a
Address: addressline1 and address line 2
Phone: a
Email: a
Invoice Prefix: a
Footer Text: a

Later I will make a pdf file using this data as well.
Therefore, I need to get the values individually.
Anybody can help me about this?
I am searching in google and youtube but nothing works. some methods doesn't work becasue very old, and most of the methods shows how to create a list graving values from database. I don't want to create any list. I will have only one data in the whole database and i want use this everywhere in the app.

Lots of talking :p

Answer (score 1):

here you just get one record back as your data model

```
Future<CompanyProfile> getProfile(int id) async {

 final db = await database;
 final maps = await db.query(tableName, where: '_id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);

 return CompanyProfile.fromMap(maps[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using a db.rawQuery instead of db.query. Then you can format the query as a standard SQL expression to control which columns are returned.

```
// Will query the whole table similar to SELECT * FROM tableName
Database db = await instance.database;
var queryResult = await db.query('tableName');
```

Instead

```
// Will query the columns selected from the table
Database db = await instance.database;
var queryResult = await db.rawQuery('SELECT fldColName1, fldColName2 FROM tableName');
```

It's worth noting that you can also achieve INNER JOINS, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY etc. when using a raw query.